# Header atropelando o Echo

Tags: php

Estou tentando utilizar o seguinte código:

```
echo "<script>alert('Erro. Tente novamente.');</script>";   
$insertGoTo ="pág.php";
header("Location: $insertGoTo");
```

só que, ao executar o código `header()` atropela o `echo` e a mensagem do `alert` não é exibida.

Tem como eu fazer ele exibir a mensagem antes do redirecionamento do `header()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **PHP-HEADER**
>   <sub>Lembre-se que header() deve ser chamada antes de qualquer saída real é enviado, seja por tags HTML normais, linhas em branco em um arquivo, ou a partir de PHP. É um erro muito comum ler código com incluir , ou exigir , funções ou outra função de acesso a arquivos, e ter espaços ou linhas em branco que estão de saída antes de header() é chamado. O mesmo problema existe quando usar um único arquivo PHP / HTML.</sub>

<sub>*Os `header's` são sempre enviados antes das saidas, por isso se você usar `Location + echo` a página será redirecionada sem a exibição conteúdo.*</sub>

Além da alternativa do javascript, que não garante o funcionamento caso esteja desabilitado no navegador do usuário, você pode usar o header com `refresh`, ou a `meta-refresh`, ou combinar as 3 opções, garantindo a funcionalidade e acessibilidade:

```
•[PHP]  | header( "refresh:5;url={$insertGoTo}" )
•[HTML] | <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
•[JS]   | Countdown exibindo o tempo restante para o redirecionamento com link direto
```

---

<sub>**#Alternativa 1**</sub>

usando o próprio `header` do PHP.

```
header( "refresh:5;url={$insertGoTo}" );
echo 'você será redirecionado...';
```

---

<sub>**#Alternativa 2**</sub>

Uma alternativa é usar a `meta-refresh`, que garante que o usuário será redeirecionado mesmo que o javascript esteja desabilitado.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

<sub>**exemplo baseado em HTML5**</sub>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?php echo $insertGoTo;?>" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>alert('Erro. Tente novamente.');</script>
    <p>Você será redirecionado em 5 segundos.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Caraca que aula haha! Valeu ajudou muito cara!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou :)

Answer (score 5):

Se você quer que o utilizador leia então tem de fazer esse redirecionamento no lado do cliente também.

Uma vez que o alert pára o script, a próxima linha de javascript vai ser corrida quando a a janela fechar usando por exemplo o `window.location`, ou `window.location.replace` (que tem a vantagem de não poluir o history com a mesma página).

Exemplo:

```
echo "<script>
  alert('Erro. Tente novamente.');
  window.location.replace('pág.php');
</script>";
```

Comment: O seu jeito da certo também cara :D Valeu pela ajuda!